# C# getting json with array in it from Cosmos db

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I need to retrieve the following JSON from my CosmosDb, but I think the C# code (which works for a simple JSON structure), needs help.
The response just shows

```
{ RolePermission[0]  } 



var response = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<RolePermission>(
                       UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("demo", "RoleMenus"), queryOptions)
                       .Where(f => f.RoleName == roleName).AsEnumerable().ToArray();
```

and the JSON is:

```
{
"id": "1",
"RoleName": "Admin",
"Menus": [
    {
        "Item": "Admin",
        "Display": "Admin",
        "Granted": true
    },
    {
        "Item": "Users",
        "Display": "Users",
        "Granted": true
    }
],
}
```

The Class defn, I want to get it into is:

```
public class RolePermission
{
    [DisplayName("Role Name")]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public List<Menus> Menus { get; set; }
}

public class Menus
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public bool Granted { get; set; }
}
```

I just need the menus part of the JSON

Thanks

Comment: may be you need to cast it?

Comment: What is the structure of your C# class?

Comment: Ok, just realized I did'nt put in the class, but have now, in the question

Comment: `this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<List<RolePermission>>`?

Comment: @Jay , then the f.RoleName fails as List<RolePermission> does not contain a defn for RoleName

Comment: Tried this, but nada,  .Where(f => f.RoleName == roleName).ToList(); 
and RoleNmae is correct

Comment: I just need the menus part of the JSON

Comment: try adding this. .Where(f => f.RoleName == roleName).Select(x=>x.Menus).ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the data that you provided and the code , it should return the list you need "Menus"
with the below query

```
var response = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<RolePermission>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("demo", "RoleMenus"), queryOptions).Where(f => f.RoleName == roleName).ToList();
```

Make sure you have the correct data inserted with the field **`RoleName`** in the container.